# Setting Up Node & NPM

Tags: node.js, npm, mean.io

I have installed MEAN IO a few times. Everytime I get it installed I can usually get one project going and then things just stop working. For example I have one project going. But then when I go to create a new project now it says commands are not found
gulp
mean init myApp
bower

So I installed with the installer at `https://nodejs.org/en/`

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:~/bin:$PATH"
```

I have node_modules at

```
usr/local/lib/node_modules
```

But I also have packages at

```
/usr/local/bin/
```

Either way I cant get these commands to run... Any ideas how I can get things setup and solid?

Answer (score 0):

Try installing mean-cli, bower and gulp globally, like so:

`npm install -g mean-cli bower gulp`